# TOC issue with word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to generate a table of contents for a book I am writing. I have gone through the process of highlighting headings and applying a style to them. I am using 3 heading styles. When I try to generate the automatic TOC it is including body text that I have not highlighted when applying heading styles. For example the chapter 1 sub heading also includes about a page and a half of body text which is bold. Then the TOC is ok to about chapter 9 and it includes more body text again in bold. I am at a loss to understand why this is happening and would be grateful if you could help. It is almost as though the body text is linked to the heading somehow.

Comment: Try resetting the style of the offending body text (then re-apply whatever style it should have) and see if that doesn't fix things up.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to generate the automatic TOC it is including body text that I have not highlighted when applying heading styles.

This behavior certainly is due to the offending text having an outline-level style applied, perhaps only to a small part of the paragraph.

Try resetting the style of the offending body text, then re-apply whatever style it should have. That should fix it.